# CSS3 Multiple Animations Safari

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm having trouble using multiple CSS3 animations running in Safari, the first runs ok but the second flickers a lot. Both part of the animation work okay alone.

(In SASS)

```
// First Anim
@include keyframes(init) {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -20850px 0px;
  }
}


// Second anim
@include keyframes(play) {
  from {
    background-position: 0px -227px;
  }
      to {
    background-position: -13066px -227px;
      }
}

@include vendor-prefix(animation, 
        (
         init 5s steps(75),
          play 2s 5s steps(47) infinite
        )
);
```

Comment: Can you post a sample with JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zizzfusion/tF5zk/16/

Comment: Yes I know it works in Chrome but the question was pointing to Safari where it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I've tried it in Safari as well and I don't see any flickering there either. Sorry.

Comment: To be clear it's only at the very end of the animation that the problems seems to occur (I'm testing it on Windows Safari) and I've had it reported that the problem's also on iOS. I'm guessing it's to do with changing the background position on the y axis for the second animation?